# IAM Policy and IAM Policy Attachment is not getting created when Applying

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've written a IAM Policy and Policy Attachment for a Lambda Function, It appears in the Plan stage but doesn't seem to apply it. When doing an apply it gets skipped and act like it doesn't exist in the plan.

I can seem anything wrong with my Terraform code, can someone double check this?

```
   data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "LambdaReingestFirehose"
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name        = "lambda-role"

  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_policy_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:GetLogEvents",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cloudwatch_log.arn}:*",
    ]

    effect = "Allow"
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "firehose:PutRecordBatch",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.firehose.arn
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowXRayLogging"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "xray:PutTraceSegments",
      "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
    ]
    # This has to be left as wildcarded as the above actions do not support resource level permissions at this time.
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_111: "Ensure IAM policies does not allow write access without constraints"
    # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_356: "Ensure no IAM policies documents allow "*" as a statement's resource for restrictable actions"
    sid    = "NICCreateAndDestroyAccess"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
      "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  name   = "lambda-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_policy_doc.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy_role_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_policy.arn
}

# Generate the lambda package files.
data "template_file" "template_file" {
  count    = length(local.lamdba_file_list)
  template = file(element(local.lamdba_file_list, count.index))
}

resource "local_file" "files" {
  count    = length(local._file_list)
  content  = element(data.template_file.template_file[*].rendered, count.index)
  filename = "../build/lambda/${basename(element(local.lamdba_file_list, count.index))}"
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_archive" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../build/lambda"
  output_path = local.lambda_output_path
  depends_on = [
    local_file.files
  ]
}

# Create the lambda function
# The lambda function to reingest data from compressed format which has failed on that failed kinesis splunk transformer.

resource "aws_lambda_function" "function" {
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_116: "Ensure that AWS Lambda function is configured for a Dead Letter Queue(DLQ)"
  # DLQ not required failures move logs into S3
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_173: "Check encryption settings for Lambda environmental variable"
  # No sensitive values held in environmental variables.
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_272: "Ensure AWS Lambda function is configured to validate code-signing"
  # checkov:skip=CKV_AWS_115: "Ensure that AWS Lambda function is configured for function-level concurrent execution limit"
  function_name = "${local.environment}-k-lambda"
  filename      =  data.archive_file.lambda_archive.output_path
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "lambda_handler.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_archive.output_base64sha256
  runtime          = "python3.8"
  timeout          = 360
  memory_size      = local.memory[terraform.workspace]
  environment {
    variables = {
      ENV                      = local.environment
    }
  }
  tracing_config {
    mode = "Active"
  }

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
    subnet_ids         = aws_subnet.private_subnet[*].id
  }
}
```

When the apply has finished I get the following error:

```
 Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): InvalidParameterValueException: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2 
        │ {
        │   RespMetadata: {
        │     StatusCode: 400,
        │     RequestID: "a015e45c-1ab4-4565-8a73-c01df192506d"
        │   },
        │   Message_: "The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2", 
        │   Type: "User"  
        │ }
```

I've reviewed the apply stage and it seems to skip creating

- data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_policy_doc"
- resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_policy"
- resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy_role_attachment"

Can anyone support me on this?

Comment: Steps to debug -

1. Create the role at first
2. Add the Lambda creation code and mention the Role ARN directly in the role argument of Lambda

Comment: What is the relevant plan output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks good so far and you have covered the suggestion in the error message. Hence I suggest adding below to the sid: NICCreateAndDestroyAccess

```
"ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
"ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"
```

as defined in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.html

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
```